# How to group by two column in R but with if statment for second?

Tags: r, dataframe

I can't found any help lf internet.
I have 3 cols in .sav file loaded to R studio.

Is `M with values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and `label: weight`, and  `N with values 1,2,3` and `label diet`.

I want group by it by these columns, but for `N` col I want only pick those where value is 1. Also I have last column with age data `A`.

I wrote this:

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(M, N) %>% 
  summarize(values = mean(A, na.rm = TRUE))
```

And I got group by but for all N.
I tried something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  group_by(M, N == 1) %>% 
  summarize(values = mean(A, na.rm = TRUE))
```

but I got again group for all categories from N with NA etc.

Expcted: I want only group_by by M - all values, and N where value =1.

How should that group by looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a group by 'M' and `summarise` the filtered 'A'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(M) %>% 
   summarise(values = mean(A[N == 1], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or another option is to have a `filter` in between, but this would also remove the groups where there are no 'N' as 1

```
df %>%
   filter(N == 1) %>%
   group_by(M) %>%
   summarise(values = mean(A, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Ou! Awesome, I wouldn't have thought of that myself!. Thank u very much for fast help :) I will tick answer in 10min